# Javascript matching "rgb(xx,xx,xx)" with regular expression regEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would highly appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction on this. I have an array "cArr" and within this array I have 2 elements. What I would like to do is to match the "rgb(xx,xx,xx)"and push it to an array "rgbArr"; The issue that I am encountering is with regEx.

Here is my code:

```
var cArr = ["id0{shape:round,rgb(24,23,12)}","id1{shape:long,weight:heavy,rgb(20,20,20)}","id2{shape:elongated,weigth:light,rgb(15,24,8)}"];


for(var i=cArr.length -1; i>=0; i--)
{
  if(cArr[i].match(matchColors))
  {
    rgbArr.push(cArr[i]);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(rgbArr);
```

Comment: The regex pattern to match "rgb(24,23,12)" would be like "rgb\\(d+,d+,d+\\)", assuming decimal values. Not posting an answer because I do not get your loop as you seem to have multiple rgb values in one string and are pushing the whole string... do you wand to puch matched part only? If so, first match or all matches?

Comment: please clarify your question: why do you have the break? Do you want to catch only the last rgb(...)? What would be the desired output in the example?

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev, I would like to punch matched parts only. So if the array has 5 elements and if all of them has "rgb(xx,xx,xx)" tags then I would like to copy just the "rgb(xx,xx,xx)" to rgbArr. Thank you.

Comment: @Combustion007, in your sample input there is no quotes around comma before id1, which causes first element of array to contain two rgb walues. Is it as intended? If so, do you want them both? Any preferences with order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify your question (seem my comment above), for the time being try something like this. (But this doesn't give you the multiple rgb colors in the 1st element...)

```
var matchColors=/.*?(rgb\([^)]*\)).*/;

var cArr = ["id0{shape:round,rgb(24,23,12)},id1{shape:long,weight:heavy,rgb(20,20,20)}","id2{shape:elongated,weigth:light,rgb(15,24,8)}","sdf"];

var rgbArr=[];

for(var i=cArr.length -1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(cArr[i].match(matchColors)) {
        var x = cArr[i].replace(matchColors,"$1");
        rgbArr.push(x);
//      break;
    }
}

console.log(rgbArr);​
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I would like to copy all the "rgb(xx,xx,xx)" matched tags from the "cArr" elements to "rgbArr". So if the "cArr" array has 5 elements and if all of them has "rgb(xx,xx,xx)" tags then I would like to copy just the "rgb(xx,xx,xx)" to rgbArr. Thank you.

Comment: ok, so decide :) Your original question had multiple rgb(...) in the 1st element, my code doesn't handle that. But now you've changed the question. So if you know that each element will have at most 1 rgb(), then my code does what you ask for.

Comment: thank you. I realized it was a typo which I didn't notice until your inquiry. So I fixed it. This really helps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrestling with this issue today and have a slightly more simplified solution to this issue which uses a slightly different Regular Expression along with JavaScripts 'match' function (I have wrapped it up in a function so that we can reuse this functionality as required):

```
function parseRGB ( string ) {
    var rgbRegex = /(rgb\([^)]*\))/gi;
    var rgbArray = string.match(rgbRegex); 

    return rgbArray;
}
```

Now simply call the function with the value you want to check. E.g.

```
parseRGB( '-moz-linear-gradient( top, rgb(68, 68, 68), rgb(153, 153, 153))' );
```

Which will return the following array:

```
[ "rgb(68, 68, 68)", "rgb(153, 153, 153)" ]
```

A few things to note:

- If no RGB matches are found this function will return null.
- JavaScripts match string function will automatically put all occurances into an array for you. It can take a regular expression as a parameter.
- This can handle multiple rgb values if they exist in the string to be checked.

Hope this helps someone.